# Insert new fields to document at given array index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure in a MongoDB collection :

```
{
  "A" : [ {
      "B" : [ { ... } ]
  } ]
}
```

I'd like to update this to :

```
{
  "A" : [ {
      "B" : [ { ... } ],
      "x" : [],
      "y" : { ... }
  } ]
}
```

In other words, I want the "x" and "y" fields to be added to the first element of the "A" array without loosing "B".

Comment: Do you've multiple objects in `A` array ? To which object do you wanted to push `x` & `y` beside `B` ?

Comment: @whoami No other objects in array `A` and `x` and `y` will only go into `A[0]` but they must not overwrite `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as there is only one object in `A` array you could simply do as below :

**Sample Collection Data :**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e7c3cadc16b5679b4aeec26"),
  A:[
     {
       B: [{ abc: 1 }]
     }
    ]
}
```

**Query :**

```
/** Insert new fields into 'A' array's first object by index 0 */
db.collection.updateOne(
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5e7c3f77c16b5679b4af4caf") },
    { $set: { "A.0.x":  [] , "A.0.y" : {abcInY :1 }} }
  )
```

**Output :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7c3cadc16b5679b4aeec26"),
    "A" : [ 
        {
            "B" : [ 
                {
                    "abc" : 1
                }
            ],
            "x" : [],
            "y" : {
                "abcInY" : 1.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or Using positional operator [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) :

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId("5e7c3cadc16b5679b4aeec26") , 'A': {$exists : true}},
    { $set: { "A.$.x":  [] , "A.$.y" : {abcInY :1 }} }
  )
```

**Note :** Result will be the same, but functionally when positional operator is used fields `x` & `y` are inserted to first object of `A` array only when `A` field exists in that documents, if not this positional query would not insert anything (Optionally you can check `A` is an array condition as well if needed). But when you do updates using index `0` as like in first query if `A` doesn't exist in document then update would create an `A` field which is an object & insert fields inside it (Which might cause data inconsistency across docs with two types of `A` field) - Check below result of 1st query when `A` doesn't exists.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7c3f77c16b5679b4af4caf"),
    "noA" : 1,
    "A" : {
        "0" : {
            "x" : [],
            "y" : {
                "abcInY" : 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think your first solution should work. I've added another solution using piplines within update.

Answer (score 0):

However, I think I was able to get anothe@whoami Thanks for the suggestion, I think your first solution should work. However, I think I was able to get another solution to this though I'm not sure if its better or worse (performance wise?) than what you have here. My solution is:

`db.coll.update( { "_id" : ObjectId("5e7c4eb3a74cce7fd94a3fe7") }, [ { "$addFields" : { "A" : { "x" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "y" : { "abc" } } } } ] )`

The issue with this is that if "A" has more than one array entry then this will update all elements under "A" which is not something I want. Just out of curiosity is there a way of limiting this solution to only the first entry in "A"?

Comment: `aggregation pipeline` in `update` operations is introduced starting MongoDB v`4.2`, which is a powerful way to update documents - which is only needed for complex updates where you need to do some operations with existing fields or use MongoDB's operator. And `$set` is nothing but `$addFields` in aggregation, if you look query executing in back-end, end of the day it will do the same, For your basic need you need not to use pipeline :-)